# Android Media Player Get Duration returns 0

Tags: android, ftp, mp3, android-mediaplayer

I am coding media player that streams media from my server.
But when i try to achieve duration of the mp3 from its metadata but it returns 0. However i am using `json` so i manually added it in seconds and than replaced it wherever i have to use the duration. But now its a serious problem because i cannot also use `seekTo()`. Please guys help me.

See, this mp3 url can return its duration and also seeking works:
http://www.tonycuffe.com/mp3/tail%20toddle.mp3 it returns correct duration!

But when the same mp3 file, i download and put to my ftp folder (hostgator business server) it returns 0.

So i think that problems goes with my server. But i can't encounter the problem.

Comment: Please anyone reply??